# swift, xcode: simulator window is tiny

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, simulator

Often times, when I run the project, the simulator window pops up really small, with no iphone around it. Just a tiny little rectangle that cannot be resized. Does anybody know why this happens? Look at the image below to see what it looks like. Note: it is a screenshot of just a portion of the screen, so it makes the window look bigger than it is.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

not much context provided, you can try, after selecting the simulator, on the top task bar click window -> point accurate (command + 2)

Let us know if this works

Comment: The question is not how to resize the window, it’s why this happens at all.

Comment: Yeah, I actually cannot resize the window this way. And the iphone around the screen does not appear either.